# 2sxc: List Count Minus Unpublished

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

How do you get a list of visible/published items. I am doing a List.Count(), but only want to include visible items in the count. I thought about looping through the list but the items don't seem to have a visible property.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an "IsPublished" property. Check out the (work in progress) new API wiki we're working on (and please contribute :) - https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/Dynamic-Entity

Now for your special case there may be a surprise: *by default* the logged in editor sees different items in the default stream than the not logged in user. So in the very default, if you loop (or LINQ) all the items with xyz.Count(e => e.IsPublished) the total would be different for the editor than for the end-user, because the editor would see more draft-items. So the editor would see **fewer** published items.

This may be counter-intuitive at first, but by *default* if an item exists as published and draft, the end-user will see the published, and the editor will see the draft. So the count would respect that.

I'm saying this is the default, because if you use the visual query designer, you'll see that by default, the standard cache delivers all data to a Published-Datasource, which then passes the "Default" stream to the module-data-source. This "Default" stream adapts to the current user. You could also use the "Published" or "Draft" stream and exclusively work (count) these.